# Keep web workers running when lock screen on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, progressive-web-apps, web-worker

I use Web Workers API to update content for my PWA every 15 mins. It runs very smoothly on PC. But on iOS, i see it will be paused when i minimized the app or turn off phone's screen.

I tried the example from here (https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_webworker) and got the same problem. I press start, the number will start to count (interval is 500ms), i back to home screen and come back after 5 mins, but the number is just 50.

So, is there any way to keep Web Workers keep running even though minimize the app or lock screen?